# Make SQLite errors specific and not just SQLITE_ERROR in express/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite

So basically I have a similar block written in Express:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

const data = {};
const db = new sqlite3.Database("sqlite/test.db");
db.run("INSERT INTO [Employees]([Name]) VALUES(?)", [name], function (err) {
  if (err) {                     //this is the error block
    data.error = err.code;
    data.status = 0;
  }
  else {                         //this is the success block
    data.data = { Name: name, Id: this.lastID };
    data.status = 1;
  }

  db.close();
  res.send(data);
});
```

This does what it looks like, just a simple insert statement and its callback. The update, select and delete operations are literally all the same.

But whenever I get errors (syntax error, missing fields, missing tables, yada yada), I always just get `{errNo: 0, code: "SQLITE_ERROR"}` in my `err` argument, which is annoyingly unspecific and unhelpful.

Is there a way to fix the error handling and make it not insanity inducing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/node-js-sqlite3-error-handling/) is the closest thing I found to documentation on the error object. You probably want to look at `err.message`.

Comment: Thank you! Works. I don't understand why these properties aren't exposed when I try to send the whole object.